# I rhyme with omega

Tags: riddle, rhyme, knowledge, geography

> The place of the birth of a short-reigning king,
>   the fifth of his name and the last of his kind.
>   As well as the place of his death one cruel spring,
>   the label of genocide later assigned.
>   Though found in the tropics, there's not too much heat;
>   I rhyme with omega, just lately named seat.

What am I?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Are you

> Gitega  (in Ruanda-Urundi / Burundi)

The place of the birth of a short-reigning king,
the fifth of his name and the last of his kind.
As well as the place of his death one cruel spring,
the label of genocide later assigned.

> This seems to describe the life and death of Ntare V of Burundi, the last monarch of Burundi.

Though found in the tropics, there's not too much heat;

> Gitega's climate is classified as warm and temperate

I rhyme with omega, just lately named seat.

> Rhymes with omega (Gitega) and is the capital of Burundi as of December 24, 2018.